# VBScript, cant end my project

Tags: vbscript

this is the last part of my script

```
MsgBox("text")
    vbOK
WScript.Quit
End If
x=MsgBox("text",1,"text")
    vbOK
If vbOK Then
do
Loop
    vbCancel
If vbCancel Then
WScript.Quit
    MsgBox("text")
```

but somehow it wont work. i use vbsedit, but when i press start it tell me to add 'end',so i do but then it tell me to add'if'. after ive done that it tells me to add 'end' again, and so it goes on.

how can i fix it?
im new to VBS and spent 5h trying to find a solution.

Comment: See [ask]. This is among the worst questions I've seen today.

Comment: What he means is that your question is of low quality. He´s not mad at you but wants you to read (and follow) the instructions in the link he presented. And I agree with him. Examples: `x=MsgBox("text",1,"text")
    vbOK` does not make sense -- what is vbOK? A sub? It surely is not what the MsgBox example in VBScript´s documentation (and anywhere else) shows. If you google the MsgBox function, you´ll see how it is used. Next example would be: End If without If, and vice versa. Next: You present an incomplete snippet, not a self-contained simple example. And so on :( so what do you expect?

Comment: And if you look at John's profile, you'll see he has given thousands and thousands of useful answers. You asked your first. If this makes you feel that he is wrong when he says it´s the worst question he has seen today, and really believe your question is today´s best question, then you should either be eager to learn and improve, alternatively, better delete your question and/or your account altogether. Sorry, you are not the first nor the only new user telling those willing to help that they are mad, stupid or plainly dumb. Please reconsider this notion. Your future here is finite otherwise.

Comment: i have 3days experience with vbs. i saw online that u can change button functions by doing "vb" and thn button name. im trying to make the buttons acctually have a function insted of having 'ok' and 'cancel' do the same thing. thats why vbok

Comment: Please find a tutorial (e.g. [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/)) and learn the basics of the language first. The code you posted is not even valid VBScript syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> Displays a message in a dialog box, waits for the user to click a button, and returns a value indicating which button the user clicked.
>
> `MsgBox(prompt[, buttons][, title][, helpfile, context])`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> [...]
>
> *buttons*
>   Numeric expression that is the sum of values specifying the number and type of buttons to display, the icon style to use, the identity of the default button, and the modality of the message box. See Settings section for values. If omitted, the default value for buttons is 0.

As you can see the button layout of VBScript message boxes is controlled via the second parameter, and the function's return value indicates which button was pressed by the user.

If for instance you want to present a user with a yes/no choice you could do something like this:

```vbs
choice = MsgBox("question", vbYesNo, "title")

Select Case choice
  Case vbYes : MsgBox "User pressed 'Yes'."
  Case vbNo  : MsgBox "User pressed 'No'."
  Case Else  : MsgBox "Something unexpected happened.", , "Error"
End If
```

Comment: rly helped. but still got a few issues. id like to give a function to cancel button and ok button. cancel whould cancel the prosses and ok whould continue it. btw im doing it for inputbox and had a issue with where u wrote "choice = MsgBox("question", vbYesNo, "title")" it whould make the 'title' in the inputbox and insted title it as '1'.

Comment: If you don't know how to "cancel the process" depending on an MsgBox function call result, even after Ansgar's answer, please post a new question. This will force you to specify exactly what you mean by "cancel the process". And: If the original question (this one here) is answered, please accept the answer that answered you question best ;)